# How to configure bind to not to do internal recursion?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, internal-dns

While quering my authoritative-name-server (implemented with bind locally in VM) for "A" record of "host1.cool.com", it internally resolves the query using recursion (maybe) and returns with the actual "A" record. I need the nameserver to reply with one CNAME record each query, the recursive resolver can issue multiple dns query to resolve the name. But, I have not been able to do that with setting "recursion no;" to "named.conf.options".

My query (from another machine):

```
dig A @192.168.0.115 host1.cool.com
```

Response is the whole CNAME chain, and the final answer:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
host1.cool.com.     5   IN  CNAME   host2.cool.com.
host2.cool.com.     5   IN  CNAME   host3.cool.com.
host3.cool.com.     5   IN  CNAME   host4.cool.com.
host4.cool.com.     5   IN  CNAME   host5.cool.com.
host5.cool.com.     5   IN  CNAME   host6.cool.com.
host6.cool.com.     5   IN  CNAME   host7.cool.com.
host7.cool.com.     5   IN  A   22.33.44.55
```

I want the nameserver to respond with just one CNAME record even for the "A" query. Maybe something like this:

```
host1.cool.com CNAME host2.cool.com
```

My named.conf.local file

```
zone "cool.com" IN {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/db.cool.com";
  allow-transfer { none; };
};
```

And named.conf.options file

```
options {
  directory "/var/cache/bind";
  auth-nxdomain no;
  allow-query { any; };
  allow-transfer { none; };
  recursion no;
};
```

db.cool.com file

```
@TTL 5S

@  IN  SOA  @ hostmaster.cool.com. (
  0, 3H, 1H, 1W, 3H )

@  IN  NS  ns1.cool.com.
@  IN  NS  ns2.cool.com.
@  IN  A   98.87.76.65

ns1  IN  A  10.20.30.40
ns2  IN  A  10.20.30.41

host1.cool.com.  IN  CNAME  host2.cool.com.
host2.cool.com.  IN  CNAME  host3.cool.com.
host3.cool.com.  IN  CNAME  host4.cool.com.
host4.cool.com.  IN  A      22.33.44.55
```

How to configure bind not to internally use recursion to resolve the query?

Answer (score 0):

This type of behaviour would break CNAMEs. If you don't want to get the IP-Address, you shouldn't query `A/AAAA` resource records (RRs), but ask the server explicitly for `CNAME`.

Quoting RFC 1034:

> CNAME RRs cause special action in DNS software.  When a name server
> fails to find a desired RR in the resource set associated with the
> domain name, it checks to see if the resource set consists of a CNAME
> record with a matching class.  If so, the name server includes the
> CNAME record in the response and restarts the query at the domain name
> specified in the data field of the CNAME record.  The one exception to
> this rule is that queries which match the CNAME type are not
> restarted.
>
> For example, suppose a name server was processing a query with for
> USC- ISIC.ARPA, asking for type A information, and had the following
> resource records:
>
> ```
> USC-ISIC.ARPA   IN      CNAME   C.ISI.EDU
>
> C.ISI.EDU       IN      A       10.0.0.52
> ```
>
> Both of these RRs would be returned in the response to the type A
> query, while a type CNAME or * query should return just the CNAME.

Recursion, in DNS-speak, is when your DNS server resolves names starting from the root zone, recursively descending zones until reaching the terminal label an querying the desired RR.